# How to add a package such as axios to a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, javascript-import

I'm trying to make a chrome extension and I wanted to use the axios package. When I try to test my code in Chrome I get this error in the console:
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. See the [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fISK8.png) for more context.

I've installed the package by executing ***npm install axios*** in the console. Sorry if this is a rudimentary question, I don't really know what I am doing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: type the error message in the question.

Comment: did you fix this problem, I want to using axios in google chrome extension too.@acohen89

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External modules like axios would need to be bundled into your chrome extension in order for it to work as you intend. You can use a bundler like `webpack` in order to do this, but there is a decent amount of configuration needed to get up and running.

I would recommend using the `fetch` API as an alternative. It's already freely available in chrome extensions and works in very similar way to axios.

A fuller code example comparing `fetch` to `axios`:
https://blog.logrocket.com/axios-or-fetch-api/

Comment: oh sick. Thanks!

Comment: How do you have to configure webpack in order to include `axios`? I can't change `axios` in favor of `fetch` as I'm relying on high level APIs provided by `axios` (interceptors).